KIE Data Model Constraints Range Syntax
I am using the KIE DMN plugin. I want to define a constraint on a data type.
The editor provides a dialog box for "Data Type Constraints".
The dialog contains a dropdown for constraint type: Enumeration, Expression, and Range.
I am trying to define an open ended constraint e.g  >=0.
I have tried the following constraints and nothing seems to work:

>=0
">=0"
">= 0"
[>=0]
"[>=0]"
[0..*)

For now, I have to settle with [0..1000000000].
I do not like having an arbitrary MAX.
Does anybody have a solution for using this quirky Data Type Constraing dialog box?

Hi there should be no issue in the scenario you describe. In the attached screenshot I used 'expression' constraint type to define desired range.


I concur with @jomarko

What tool are you using?

I am using https://sandbox.kie.org/dev/, what is the latest version of https://sandbox.kie.org/. The same is available also as VSCode extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.bamoe-developer-tools or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kie-group.dmn-vscode-extension, however the VSCode extensions are currently not released as often as needed. So the latest is the first link only.
